# add unique id for JSON data with R

Tags: arrays, json, r, nested

I am a beginner with R. My situation is I have a JSON dataset with a nested array. In the JSON file, one institution looks like this:

```
{
    "website": "www.123.org",
    "programs": [
        {
            "website": "www.111.com",
            "contact": "Jim"
        },
        {
            "website": "www.222.com",
            "contact": "Han"
        }
    ]
}
```

To each institution, there may be one program or may be more. I have more than 100 hundreds institution and nearly two hundreds programs in the JSON. I want to ad id for each institution and idpr for each program. Finally, i hope i can get a data.frame that looks like:

```
id idpr website     websitepr   contactpr
1  1    www.123.org www.111.com Jim
1  2    www.123.org www.222.com Han
2  1    www.345.org www.aaa.com Lily
3  1    www.567.org www.bbb.com Jack
3  2    www.567.org www.ccc.com Mike
3  3    www.567.org www.ddd.com Minnie
.........
```

I tried to write a nested loop like this:
     count<-0
     for (n in json_data){
     count<-count+1
     id<-c(id,count)
     website<-c(website,n$website)
     countpr<-1
      for (i in n$programs){
      id<-c(id,count)
      website<-c(website,n$website)
      idpr<-c(idpr,countpr)
      websitepr<-c(websitepr,i$website)
      contactpr<-c(contactpr,i$contact)
      countpr<-countpr+1
        }
      } 
but this nested loop can not give me the result i want. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# sample data
json.file <- textConnection('[{"website":"www.123.org","programs":[{"website":"www.111.com","contact":"Jim"},{"website":"www.222.com","contact":"Han"}]},{"website":"www.345.org","programs":[{"website":"www.aaa.com","contact":"Lily"}]},{"website":"www.567.org","programs":[{"website":"www.bbb.com","contact":"Jack"},{"website":"www.ccc.com","contact":"Mike"},{"website":"www.ddd.com","contact":"Minnie"}]}]')

# read the data into an R nested list
library(rjson)
raw.data <- fromJSON(file = json.file)

# a function that will process one institution
process.one <- function(id, institution) {
   website   <- institution$website
   websitepr <- sapply(institution$programs, `[[`, "website")
   contactpr <- sapply(institution$programs, `[[`, "contact")
   data.frame(id, idpr = seq_along(websitepr),
              website, websitepr, contactpr)
}

# run the function on all institutions and put the pieces together
do.call(rbind, Map(process.one, seq_along(raw.data), raw.data))
#   id idpr     website   websitepr contactpr
# 1  1    1 www.123.org www.111.com       Jim
# 2  1    2 www.123.org www.222.com       Han
# 3  2    1 www.345.org www.aaa.com      Lily
# 4  3    1 www.567.org www.bbb.com      Jack
# 5  3    2 www.567.org www.ccc.com      Mike
# 6  3    3 www.567.org www.ddd.com    Minnie
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a 
class website {

//write all as data member

//program as object of class program

}

and use jackson api to convert it into string.
using Mapper.writeValueAsString(object of website)

jar needed are 
1.jackson-core-2.0.2.jar

1. jackson-databind-2.0.2.jar.